# VS Code integrated terminal $PATH not using ~/.bash_profile

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am having trouble trying to get the integrated VSCode terminal to properly reflect the changes I made to my ~/.bash_profile. (OSX)

I have been able to get my terminal in OSX environment to do what I want but when I try from within the integrated terminal in VSCode, I see that none of my changes are being reflected.

Specifically I'm using the `echo $PATH` to check and while this is what I supposedly want (which i get from the osx terminal)

```
/Users/username/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin
```

this is what I am getting

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin:/Users/username/anaconda3/bin
```

I have tried doing what I'm being told here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_linux-os-x but I'm not exactly sure I am doing it correctly. I am guessing I'm supposed to write `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": [ "-l" ]` to the settings.json file which I have and right now this is what my settings.json file looks like

```
{
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": [ "-l" ],
"python.pythonPath": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3",
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false
```

}

but I guess this is not the way to do things?
Other options I've found online but have no idea if they would help me or completely wreck my computer is to edit my /etc/paths file, looking for a .bashrc file, which I don't think I actually have, and `export PATH=/Users/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`... I don't know which or even if these things would help me... or even what is wrong in the first place and what file I should and should not be touching...

Comment: Taking a stab in the dark, but did you check that you are using bash in the terminal in VS Code?

Comment: yes, using echo $SHELL shows me /bin/bash, both in and out of VSCode's integrated terminal.